# How to count array inside multiple array count php

Tags: php

I was stored array inside multiple array how to count inside arrays count

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [table] => items [sku] => LUDM15 ) 
[1] => Array ( [table] => items [sku] => SEZC64 ) 
)
```

how to count inside arrays count....

Comment: use for loop to loop and perform count function inside loop.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose

```
$array1 is Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [table] => items [sku] => LUDM15 ) 
[1] => Array ( [table] => items [sku] => SEZC64 ) 
)

$count = array();
foreach ($array1  as $key => $value) {
    $count[] = count($value);
}
```

all count values will stored in  count array

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the array and then `count` the lenght of the inner arrays:

```
$array = array(array('hi', 'hello'), array('hi', 'hello'), array('hi', 'hello'));
foreach ($array as $singleArray){
  echo 'Count = ' . count($singleArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$mainArray = array ( 
    [0] => array ( [table] => items [sku] => LUDM15 ) 
    [1] => array ( [table] => items [sku] => SEZC64 ) 
)
foreach ($mainArray as $subArray){
     echo count($subArray);
}
```

---

Inside the foreach you can do whatever you want with the count of the single subArrays.